# Excel. Altering rows into columns

Tags: excel-formula

I would like to ask if someone know how to translate rows to column but alternately according to the picture:

[image]

So far I have used "transpone" but it returned bad result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select as many cells down you want, and use this CSE formula (commit with `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`):

```
=INDEX(B2:D6,N(IF({1},INT((ROW()-INDEX(ROW(),1))/COLUMNS(B2:D6))+1)),N(IF({1},MOD(ROW()-INDEX(ROW(),1),COLUMNS(B2:D6))+1)))
```

Comment: What are you getting?
Two things to check:
1) Did you select multiple cells in the column (e.g., column `F`) before you typed in the formula?
2) Did you press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter` after you typed in the formula?

Comment: Microsoft Excel 365.